# AutoMapper mapping from type to type with nested type

Tags: c#, automapping, automapper-5

I'm using the latest version, with the instance API.

My source type:

```
public class Source {
  public string ValueX { get; set; }
  public string ValueY { get; set; }
  public string ValueZ { get; set; }
}
```

My destination type:

```
public class Destination {

  public Destination () { Inner = new Inner(); }

  public string ValueX { get; set; }

  public Inner Inner { get; set; }

  public class Inner {
    public string ValueY { get; set; }
    public string ValueZ { get; set; }
  }

}
```

My config (done in a profile):

```
  CreateMap<Source, Destination>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Inner, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src));
```

But this doesn't map the inner object. When I test the config, it throws an unhelpful `AutoMapperConfigurationException` exception.

What is the proper way to make this mapping work?

Comment: Before doing that you need to define a map between Source and Inner like CreateMap<Source, Inner>()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before doing that you need to define a map between Source and Inner like:

```
CreateMap<Source, Inner>();
```